# Compiling user entered groovy script at run time

Tags: grails, groovy

Have a scenario as below where I need to validate the groovy script for correctness.

```
class CostCalculator{

String name
String groovyScript

static constraints = {
groovyScript:static validateScript = {String script ,def obj->
        boolean status = true
        try {
            def shell = new GroovyShell()
            def data = shell.parse(script)
            data.run()
        }catch (Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace()
            status = false
        }
        if(!status){
            return "domain.script.compilation.errors"
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }
}

}
```

Problem in above code is that it runs the code and if there is any exception it throws it at runtime.

There are few things to consider:

1. groovy code should compile rather than running(As code might contain db level updates) and throwing exception.
2. groovy code should compile statically i.e. for example if we have some property missing in script, then it must get notified.

below could be example script:

```
void addCost(int x, int y,String itemName){
double cost = x*y + originalCost
Item item = SoldItem.findByItemName(itemName)
item.price += cost
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to put your groovy script in a class.

In the example you have method **addCost()**, so I would say just wrap this method in a class. ex:

```
String gScript = """
class CostCalculatorScript{
    void addCost(int x, int y,String itemName){
        double cost = x*y + originalCost
        Item item = SoldItem.findByItemName(itemName)
        item.price += cost
    }
}

"""
```

Now load and parse this script using GroovyClassLoader.

```
ClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader()
Class clazz = gcl.parseClass(gScript)
```

Verify that the loaded class have the same name as you have specified in your script.

```
assert clazz.simpleName == 'CostCalculatorScript'
```

Now the kind of solution you want does seem like static compilation. You can add the **@groovy.transform.CompileStatic** annotation to your class. But with this annotation the problem is that you can't use the dynamic finders of grails or the def keyword.

But if you still want that functionality then you should use **[@grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.0/guide/staticTypeCheckingAndCompilation.html)** annotation which is available in Grails 2.4.

Comment: I am able to use def except in scenarios where any operation is type unsafe.